# SkipWhileIterator method implementation understanding

Tags: c#, .net, linq, iterator, clr

I am reading what's happening when the CLR executes the SkipWhile method. For example, lets take that:

```
IList<string> numbers = new List<string>() 
{ 
"One","Two","Three", "Four","Five"
};
var result = numbers.SkipWhile(number => number.Length == 3);
result.ToList().ForEach(number => Console.WriteLine(number));
```

CLR will do these steps:

The C# compiler constructs a method `<Main>b__1` using the anonymous
method (`number => number.Length == 3`) in the compile time. The CLR
will instantiate an instance of `MulticastDelegate` using the
`<Main>b__1` method as a predicate to the `SkipWhile`. The CLR
instantiates an instance of the `SkipWhileIterator` iterator using
the original list and the predicate `<Main>b__1`. Due to the
deferred execution, the `SkipWhileIterator` will not execute until
the `CLR` calls the `ToList` or uses the `ForEach` method to iterate
through. The CLR executes the `ToList` method over the `SkipWhileIterator`
return from the `SkipWhile` method, and inside the
`SkipWhileIterator`, the `CLR` loops through the original list one
by one and executes the predicate over each of the items. If the
predicate returns false, then the `SkipWhileIterator` returns that
item as a result of the `SkipWhile` method; or if it returns true,
then it continues through the list until it finishes.

So far, everything is ok.

But, then I have watched implementation of the `SkipWhileIterator` from [this web site](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#2a0646c99b695eff#references).

```
 static IEnumerable<TSource> SkipWhileIterator<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate) {
       bool yielding = false;
       foreach (TSource element in source) {
          if (!yielding && !predicate(element)) yielding = true;
          if (yielding) yield return element;
       }
 }
```

But, isn't it false? In my opinion second if statement must be like that:

```
 if (yielding) {yielding=false; yield return element};
```

`Yielding`'s value **must set to false** in second if, otherwise it will not get inside the first if statement if the value is True.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once `SkipWhile` finds a value that doesn't match the predicate, it stops looking and just returns the rest of the sequence. `yielding` starts out false, so that elements won't be returned, and on the first non-match it's set to true. After that, it doesn't *want* to get into the first `if` statement again, because it already knows it's going to return the elements after that.

Comment: I have misundestood the meaning of SkipWhile method. I have though that, it will return all elements in the list, which are not matched the condition. But, it seems that, SkipWhile bypasses elements in a sequence as long as a specified condition is true and then returns the remaining elements.

Comment: yes. what you are talking about is just `Where` with a negated predicate.

Comment: Right, my fault. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to read the method documentation to understand the logic:

From [`Enumerable.SkipWhile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.skipwhile(v=vs.100).aspx):

> Bypasses elements in a sequence as long as a specified condition is true and **then returns the remaining elements.**

`yielding` isn't set to `false` again because that is the desired behavior. The predicate should only be matched **once**

Comment: Yes, I got it. I didn't pay attention while reeading from the book.